# Continuously Render to two wxglcanvas on same wxPanel through alternate rendering or two separate threads

Tags: c++, opengl, wxwidgets

I have two classes bGLpanel and bGLpanel1 derived from wxGLcanvas and bpane and bpane1 are instance of both classes respectively I want to render continuously on both wxGLcanvas(via two separate thread ) or alternatively render both.How to do it?Right now just first one(bpane) is being rendered on my App.wxPanel is part of wxNotebook.

Additional Info:

wiki.wxwidgets.org/Using_wxImage_to_load_textures_for_OpenGL I am using the example given in this link I am making two different classes as two completely different streams needed to be opened and so there are two different render methods and I dont know how to do alternate render with that example.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your display from two different threads will not work.  wxWidgets will only update the display from one main thread.  If you try, nasty, unexpected things will happen.

However, if you have two wxGLCanvas widgets, then you can render each one in turn after a refresh request and it will look just fine.

You have two choices:

1. Update one canvas on each refresh, and keep a flag so that it is done alternately.
2. Update both canvases on each refresh.

It hardly matters which you choose.  I would guess #2 myself, but it is no big deal to try both ans see which you prefer.

Something like this:

```
EVT_PAINT(MyApp::RenderRequest)

void MyApp::RenderRequest( wxPaintEvent& evt )
{
  glPlaneA->Render( evt );
  glPlaneB->Render( evt );
}
```

Comment: how to do it that alternate rendering

Comment: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Using_wxImage_to_load_textures_for_OpenGL I am using the example given in this link I am making two different classes as two completely different streams needed to be opened and so there are two different render methods and I dont know how to do alternate render with that example.